# Is there a way to authenticate a windows authenticated user in Html Agility Pack?

Tags: c#

In HttpTests there's a way to authenticate using

```
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

is there something similar in Html Agility Pack? I want to test my localhost project but it's receiving a:

> HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized You are not authorized to view this page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to authenticate a windows authenticated user in Html Agility Pack?

No,

**What is exactly the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) (HAP)?**

This is an agile HTML parser that builds a read/write DOM and supports plain XPATH or XSLT.

It is a .NET code library that allows you to parse "out of the web" HTML files. The parser is very tolerant with "real world" malformed HTML. The object model is very similar to what proposes System.Xml, but for HTML documents (or streams).

Html Agility Pack now supports Linq to Objects (via a LINQ to Xml Like interface).

**Sample applications:**

**Page fixing or generation :** You can fix a page the way you want, modify the DOM, add nodes, copy nodes, well... you name it.

**Web scanners :** You can easily get to img/src or a/hrefs with a bunch XPATH queries.

**Web scrapers :** You can easily scrap any existing web page into an RSS feed for example, with just an XSLT file serving as the binding. An example of this is provided.

[Html Agility Code Examples](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples)

Answer (score 8):

I found a blog by Jon Gallant: http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/07/htmlagilitypack-windows-authentication.html#.UJEQam8xol8

creates a new instance of HtmlWeb, creates a new WebProxy which sets UseDefaultCredentials to true, creates a new variable called document on webload sets the url to a GET request, inserts the default credentials and gets the system credentials of the application.

```
         var web = new HtmlWeb();
         web.PreRequest = delegate(HttpWebRequest webRequest)
         {
         webRequest.Timeout = 1200000;
         return true;
         };
         var proxy = new WebProxy() { UseDefaultCredentials = true };
         var doc = web.Load("http://localhost:2120", "GET", proxy, 
         CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials);


        var linksOnPage = from lnks in document.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                          where lnks.Name == "a" &&
                               lnks.Attributes["href"] != null &&
                               lnks.InnerText.Trim().Length > 0 

                          select new
                          {
                              Url = lnks.Attributes["href"].Value,
                              Text = lnks.InnerText
                          };

        linksOnPage.All(t => { Console.WriteLine(t.Text + " : " + t.Url); return true; });
```

Comment: for windows authentication, that's absolutely working