# How can get HTML Agility to authenticate against a Windows Integrated Security app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-agility-pack, iis-8

I'm trying to use HTML Agility pack to scrape a page of my app and embed it as mail body. That worked wonders on my developpement machine with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13157117/is-there-a-way-to-authenticate-a-windows-authenticated-user-in-html-agility-pack), but as soon as I published it on the remote IIS server, then I get 401.1 error pages as mail body instead.

The app uses Windows Integrated Security for authentication and authorizations, I have set the service account on the Application Pool. So I tried to set the credentials manually to use the same account as the application pool and added it to the authorized roles, and I still get the same issue.

This is the code I use to get the page:

```
var lAuthentification = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
var lProxy = new WebProxy() { Credentials = lAuthentification };
var lWeb = new HtmlWeb();
lWeb.PreRequest = delegate (HttpWebRequest webRequest)
{
    webRequest.Timeout = 1200000;
    return true;
};
var lPage = lWeb.Load(pURL, "GET", lProxy, lAuthentification);
```

I tried both that and the solution linked in the answer mantionned before, which works fine on my machine:

```
var lProxy = new WebProxy() { UseDefaultCredentials = true };
var lWeb = new HtmlWeb();
lWeb.PreRequest = delegate (HttpWebRequest webRequest)
{
    webRequest.Timeout = 1200000;
    return true;
};
var lPage = lWeb.Load(pURL, "GET", lProxy, CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials);
```

At the top of my controller I have the authorize clauses `[Authorize(Roles = @"RoleNames")]` because all the data are sensitive.
Many sources explained that when a domain account is set on the App Pool, the SPN must be set, but apparently that was [up until IIS6](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webtopics/2009/01/19/service-principal-name-spn-checklist-for-kerberos-authentication-with-iis-7-07-5/) and we're on IIS8 (Windows Server 2012), so that shouldn't be related I think.

I liked the overall idea, I didn't want to have to build the mail body with string builder and lookup the data off the database if I have a page that already has all the info, so maybe there's a way to fetch the processed razor page without making web request?

Comment: SPN is still necessary when you are tying to access a public domain name which is not belong to your server's active directory domain. If your site's domain name is www.a.com and your domain is b.com. Then you should set SPN for your site. It will tell your server whether KDC should authenticate Kerberos ticket for that user credential.  Please check what error credential are displayed in IIS log and try to access it directly. If you could not pass windows authentication directly, then please try to set SPN for your account.

Comment: It's not on a different domain, it's within the AD, in the form app.server.domain.tld. It doesn't give me any name in the logs, just a dash like it's an anonymous request.

Comment: Have you tried to disable loopbackcheck?

Comment: I did not, I didn't know about this but it works with it disabled indeed, so I looked it up and found out I can disable it on selected hostnames because [it's not recommended to disable it altogether](https://serverfault.com/a/485011/512558) and that works too. Thanks for steering me in that direction!